# USB Audio card fails to initialize after turning it off and on again

Tags: sound, usb, kubuntu, jack

I have a problem with an "E-MU Tracker Pre" USB audio card and Kubuntu. When I start the audio card for the first time since boot everything works fine, but after turning it off and on again, regardless of the delay between restarting it, there's a 90% chance it will fail to boot up. All the lights are lit up and stay like that, which is its loading sequence and should turn off in a second, but they stay frozen like that.

I can see the card in my /dev but if I try to open the sound manager or echo/cat some data directly to the card the window freezes until I turn off the card. There is a chance that the card will be recognized properly if I repeatedly turn it on and off, and it has happened once in a blue moon, but I haven't thoroughly tested it as I do not want to burn it.

Moving the AC to another USB port does not help and I can confirm that the problem did not exist in Ubuntu 11.x/12.x

The problem is gone after reboot for one launch of the AC and then reappears again. As it significantly hurts my creative flow I cannot settle for this as a 'solution'.

Up-to date Kubuntu 13.04
[dmesg log](http://pastebin.com/YUkXhAVb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to tell you this but it might be a ALSA/PulseAudio module bug, and *a regression* to boot. You should report it to launchpad, using `apport-bug alsa`, then the program will guide you through all the process. There have been several posts about similar behavior with USB's sound cards among all the distributions of Linux.

As test bed, I would try to use a LiveCD/USB and reproduce the problem, if it's still there you might want to report the problem, if it's not, then is a problem with your current system configuration that makes ALSA/PulseAudio/udev fails. If that's the case, reinstalling from scratch may fix it. Again, I'm pretty sure is a bug rather that a configuration issue.

You could give a look to the [method to report bugs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) too.

References:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1071854
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=79776
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1409936
- http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/pulseaudio-bugs/2011-March/004532.html
- http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-889870-start-0.html

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. I will look through the links supplied and submit a bug report.